# What do you mean by -3db cut off frequency in low-pass-filters?

Tags: voltage-divider, low-pass

I have a low pass filter as follows.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCkzIm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using voltage divider I get

$$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\omega RC)^2}} $$

But now I got a problem. I have been given the property of low pass filter as -3db cut off frequency. How am I supposed to put the value of \$\omega\$ if no frequency is given but only -3db?

If It helps the reader to understand more the question: Actually I have been given two resistors with 1kΩ and 5kΩ and two capacitors with 2nF and 4nF and I have to choose only three of the component, to  realize the circuit with -3db cut of frequency. So I came up with this schematic that could also be the possibility.

Comment: dB measures level, not frequency. There isn't enough information to give an answer.

Comment: Recall that dB is a ratio (Vout/Vin).

Comment: @dext0rb So yo you mean I can replace the value of Vout/Vin with -3

Comment: No, take a quick minute to review what a decibel is defined as.  That is the crux of your problem, I think.

Comment: -3dB translates to a Vout/Vin value. You have to do the algebra to separate the \$\omega\$ variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the voltage divider rule,

$$\left|\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\right| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(wRC)^2}}$$
Expressing in dB,
$$\left|\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\right|_{dB} = 20\log\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(wRC)^2}}\right)$$

at \$w=1/RC,\$
$$\left|\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\right|_{dB} = 20\log(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}) = -3.01\mathrm{dB}$$

So -3bB frequency is the frequency at which the the voltage gain of the filter falls to \$1/\sqrt2\$ times of the maximum value. For a simple RC low pass filter the -3dB frequency is given by,
$$w_c = 2\pi f_c = \frac{1}{RC}$$
or,
$$f_c = \frac{1}{2\pi RC}\tag1$$

So if you are asked to design a low pass filter with -3dB frequency = \$f_c\$, choose the value of R and C such that it satisfies equation (1).

Comment: Kinda spoonfed this one...

Comment: Good. Note that it's not exactly -3dB, but close.

Comment: @dext0rb I thought this is better than giving an answer \$f=(2\pi RC)^{-1}\$ directly.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany not exactly -3dB, but it probably is exactly what people usually *mean* when they say "-3dB", which is exactly "half" (even though "half" is more like -3.010299956639812 dB).

Answer (score 2):

$$ \omega = 2 \pi f $$

You can also get the required values for C and R for a -3dB point at a frequency \$f\$ by the formula:

$$ f = \frac{ 1 }{ 2\pi R C } $$

\$f\$ is your -3dB frequency.

Comment: Can I directly substitute the value of f as 3 and insert in that formula to get R*C

Comment: Were you told the -3 dB freuquency is 3 Hz?

Comment: @ThePhoton Nope. I have to choose the value of register and capacitor so that the circuit will be realized at -3db cut off frequency.

Comment: No matter what values of R and C you choose, your circuit will have a 3-dB cutoff frequency. The question is, what do you want that frequency to be? Different R and C values will give -3 dB at different frequencies, according to the formula given in these answers.